# Getting "Comments starting with '#' are deprecated" message via CLI

Tags: php

I have a very limited access to server php configuration files .

when I run some of my cron scripts which involves writing log files  , I am getting a warning like this

```
Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
```

I googled a lot to find the reason ,  I got to know that we need to replace the '#' with ';' in ming.ini file .

I informed this to my server admin to fix this

below is the link where I got this fix

[How to fix: PHP Deprecated errors](http://www.r00t.gr/how-to-fix-php-deprecated-comments-starting-with-are-deprecated-in-etcphp5cliconf-dming-ini-on-line-1-in-unknown-on-line-0/)

Later , for some of the scripts issue got fixed but for some of them I started getting same error in different php configuration file

eg .

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with ‘#’ are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imagick.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0

PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with ‘#’ are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
```

What actually is the problem , below is my server specification

OS : ubuntu 12 
php : 5.4

Is this a usual behaviour do  I need to change these comments from '#' to ';' in every file .

OR is this an issue with PHP 5.4 .

Please provide any information if you have or an easy way to avoid this error in application level ( code )

Thanks in advance for reading this post

Comment: Something like this should work to replace all these comments: `find /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ -name "*.ini" -exec sed -i -re 's/^(\s*)#(.*)/\1;\2/g' {} \;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the way suggested , is there any way where I could handle this in application layer instead of touching configuration file @Gumbo

Comment: @Gumbo Can you please post your comment as answer so that I could accept it .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can patch the comments with this shell command:

```
find /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ -name "*.ini" -exec sed -i -re 's/^(\s*)#(.*)/\1;\2/g' {} \;
```

It basically finds all `.ini` files below */etc/php5/cli/conf.d/* and executes *sed* on it, which replaces any `#` comment line literal by `;`.

Comment: On my server, this issue just popped up today after being untouched for years. is there a reason you can think of why yesterday that isn't a problem and today it is a problem?

Answer (score 32):

you need to find lines starting with '#' in your php.ini file and change it to ';'

Comment: Best! Short and simple as it.

Answer (score 1):

It shows that in your php.ini file have some error.To resolve it you can load default php.ini file by using below command.

It will rename your pervious php.ini file to php.ini_old.

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini_old
```

than it will copy default php.ini file to /etc/php5/apache2/ location.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to parse mysql.ini and php.ini files.
You don't control how the comments are used in those files so I suppressed the warnings just for that line.

```
$parse_sections = true;
$cfg = @parse_ini_file($file, $parse_sections);
```

I am sure there's a way would be to read the file line by line, replace the '#" comments and then use parse_ini_string() to parse the whole thing but this adds a little bit of overhead.

Answer (score -5):

You could try to set the PHP error_reporting configuration, like this:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

However, **this is only a temporary fix**. Getting a warning like this means that with some later version of PHP, it won't work any more at all, as the configuration files will be treated as invalid. Better cntact your hoster and ask them to fix it; shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I'd love to know why I'm getting constant downvotes on this answer, but no comments on what might be wrong with this answer.

Comment: Because it doesn't solve the problem, but merely counters the effects of it.  In doing so you also disable all deprecation warnings that might be triggered because of old code or wrong coding habits. And that makes the "fix" worse than the problem itself.

Comment: Downvoted because it just encourages ignoring the error instead of fixing it.

Comment: This still won't "hide" the warning if the cause was in `.user.ini` (PHP as CGI/FastCGI) - unless you made this a permanent change in php.ini (not recommended).